# jQuery logic issue with mouseover

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery('ul#reorderps ul ul li').mouseover(
    function(){
    jQuery(this).css("cursor","pointer");
    var position=   jQuery(this).position();

        jQuery("#up").click(function() {
            alert('hey');
        });
    }

    );
```

I expect that it does alerts 'hey' one time when i mouseover on that particular element. But it does it for the size of the selected li's. Whats wrong and how can i resolve it.Actually i have to pick up the element on which the mouse is over when clicking on the up id button.

here is the html snippet its actually i long html so only posting a part.

```
<ul id="reorderps">
<li>Financial</li>
<ul>
    <li>Hardware</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Product 1</li>
            <li>Product 2</li>
            <li>Product 3</li>
            <li>Product 4</li>
            <li>Product 5</li>
            <li>Product 6</li>
            <li>Product 7</li>
            <li>Product 8</li>
        </ul>
    <li>Software</li>
```

Comment: could you also add the html to the question?

Comment: @TeunPronk i have posted the snippet to html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding a click event on a mouseover event. I think your want this:

```
jQuery('ul#reorderps ul ul li').mouseover(function(){
    jQuery(this).css("cursor","pointer");
    var position=   jQuery(this).position();
    alert("MOUSEOVER");
});

jQuery("#up").click(function() {
    alert('hey');
});
```

Now if you click on the div #up, it will alert `hey` and on the LI mouseover it will say `mouseover`. If you want to have a click event on an element within the LI's. Do the following:

```
jQuery('ul#reorderps ul ul li').mouseover(function(){
    jQuery(this).css("cursor","pointer");
    var position=   jQuery(this).position();
    alert("MOUSEOVER");
})
.find("#up").click(function(){
    alert("hey");
});
```

**EDITED**

Each LI has a button up and down? Then you can do this

```
var lastHoveredLI = null;

jQuery('ul#reorderps ul ul li').mouseover(function(){
    jQuery(this).css("cursor","pointer");
    var position=   jQuery(this).position();
    lastHOveredLI = this;
});

jQuery("#up").click(function(){
    var li = $(lastHoveredLI);
});

jQuery("#down").click(function(){
    var li = $(lastHoveredLI);
});
```

Comment: actually i want to pick up which element i am over on the click of up button and then move that li up or down. So to get the reference of which element i am over i used mouseover. What alternate do you sugggest for it.

Comment: You want to move up / down an LI, you can do something like I posted as update. Add 2 buttons to each LI, with a .up and .down class. Or if what I did makes no sence, I do not understand you.

Comment: I actually just have one set of up down button for the entire hiearchy. So instead of having many buttons i just have two. And they are outside the up li list. What i have done is when i mouseover the li. I bring the position of these buttons near the li on which i am over.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question and the problem correctly you are missing one LI

it says: `jQuery('ul#reorderps ul ul li')`

Ill work with numbers here

```
<ul id="reorderps">1
<li>Financial</li>2
<ul>2
    <li>Hardware</li>3
        <ul>4
            <li>Product 1</li>5
            <li>Product 2</li>5
            <li>Product 3</li>5
            <li>Product 4</li>5
            <li>Product 5</li>5
            <li>Product 6</li>5
            <li>Product 7</li>5
            <li>Product 8</li>5
        </ul>
    <li>Software</li>
```

So I think what you need is:

`jQuery('ul#reorderps(1) ul(2) li(3)ul(4) li(5)')`

4 is the child of the LI hardware and not a direct child of the other UL, which you skipped in your function.
Not sure if it makes any difference but maybe it helps a bit :)